# Bootstrap 4. Grid columns in lists. Col-4 shows 2 columns instead of 3

Tags: bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, wow can I achieve to set 3 columns by using `col-4` class in each `li` element?:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item col-4" style="background-color:red">
      col1
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item col-4" style="background-color:yellow">  
      col2
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item col-4" style="background-color:green">   
      col3
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In that example, the last column breaks on new line:

https://jsfiddle.net/ema44eL5/

Comment: Does it need to be in an li? Or can you replace the lis with divs?

Comment: .col-4 has width of 100%. If you change it to: .col-4{width:30%;} it should fit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="list-unstyled row">
      <li class="list-group-item col-4" style="background-color:red">
      col1
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item col-4" style="background-color:yellow">  
      col2
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item col-4" style="background-color:green">   
      col3
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```